# Расширение IEnumerable<T> по маске

Tags: c#, linq

Кстати о `Linq`-однострочниках)

В общем, есть такая задача: 
Имеется `IEnumerable<string>`, содержащий в себе некоторые строки. А также есть `int[]`, содержащий в себе позиции, на которые в вышеуказанной коллекции нужно вставить пустые строки

Пример:

```
// IEnumerable<string> collection:
"Some"
"Strings"
"To"
"Test"
"Method"

// int[] mask:
1
2
4

// IEnumerable<string> result:
"Some"
""
""
"Strings"
""
"To"
"Test"
"Method"
```

Красота `Linq` в том, чтобы без каких-либо дополнительных переменных и явных циклов преобразовать коллекцию. Однако у меня без введения новой переменной решить задачу не получилось, так что хотел бы испросить у вас: какое решение будет более элегантным?)

Мои реализации:

*В лоб:*

```
int i = 0;
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (string x in collection)
{
    while (mask.Contains(i)) 
    {
        result.Add(string.Empty);
        ++i;
    }
    result.Add(x);
    ++i;
}
```

*То же, но через* `SelectMany`:

```
int i = 0;
IEnumerable<string> result = collection.SelectMany(x => {
    List<string> part = new List<string>();
    while (mask.Contains(i))
    {
        part.Add(string.Empty);
        ++i;
    }
    part.Add(x);
    ++i;
    return part; });
```

**UPD:**

Обычно это важно в подобного рода задачах, так что уточняю: `mask` является упорядоченным массивом

Comment: По идее, можно упаковать внутрь промежуточное состояние, если использовать Aggregate. Но ответ получится не «ленивый»

Comment: Учитывая, что в Linq никто кроме OrderBy не гарантирует порядок, вставка по индексам смотрится подозрительно. Плюс, ещё и обработка судя по примеру последовательная, т.е. нельзя индексы взять единоразово, после вставки надо перевычислять позиции.

Comment: Если от mask отнять последовательность { 1, 2, 3, ... }, получится как раз последовательность индексов исходной последовательности, где нужно добавлять элементы при помощи SelectMany

Comment: @VladD, интересная идея!

Comment: @Monk, с каких пор `yield` в содружестве с `foreach` не гарантирует определенного порядка? Смотрите исходный код `SelectManyIterator`) Собственно, да. Обработка последовательна, как, надеюсь, видно из примера

Comment: Insert у List не подходит?

Comment: @adrug, изначально у меня именно `IEnumerable`)

Comment: Я бы взял ваше решение "в лоб" и переписал в виде метода расширения: https://pastebin.com/VmpFerL3 как по мне, это более читабельнее и можно использовать в ленивых вычислениях

Comment: @АндрейNOP, почему не ответом?) Вариант же хороший

Comment: Ну, как я понял, вы хотите сделать это штатными средствами Linq (однострочником), я же предлагаю другой путь

Comment: @АндрейNOP, так-то да, но мое условие в лице «однострочника» поставлено спортивного интереса ради. А так, если кто будет искать решение подобной задачи, Ваш метод придётся очень кстати)

Comment: гарантируется, что в массиве int индексы которые точно есть? или может получиться что в последовательность два элемента, а в массиве int стоит индекс - 100?

Comment: @Grundy, кстати, хороший вопрос! Нет. Не гарантируется

Comment: И что в таком случае должно происходить?

Comment: @Grundy, такие индексы должны игнорироваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё одна вариация той же идеи с предварительной обработкой.

Создадим словарь:

```
var dict = mask.OrderBy(n => n)
               .Select((n, idx) => n - idx - 1)
               .GroupBy(n => n)
               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Имея это, получаем такой запрос:

```
Enumerable.Repeat("", dict.TryGetValue(-1, out var k) ? k : 0).Concat(
    collection.SelectMany((s, idx) =>
        Enumerable.Repeat("", dict.TryGetValue(idx, out var t) ? t : 0)
                  .Prepend(s))
);
```

Первая строка нужна для случая, когда в маске есть индекс 0.

Comment: От первой строки можно избавиться, если заменить `Prepend` на `Append`

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Можно, но тогда не сработает с _последними_ индексами.

Comment: Ага, понял, спасибо. Но с другой стороны в вопросе не сказано что надо делать в таких ситуациях, например, в исходном массиве лежит всего три строки, а в `mask` лежит `{ 10 }`

Comment: Если посмотреть решение автора "в лоб", то оно в конец тоже ничего не пишет

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хм. Пожалуй, это моя логическая ошибка. Нельзя работать с индексами маски, которые явно выходят за границы коллекции строк, но почему бы не расширить ее, если индексы соседствуют с конечным?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, как вам будет угодно ;)

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, отличную идею подал [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd):

> Если от mask отнять последовательность { 0, 1, 2, 3, ... }, получится как раз последовательность индексов исходной последовательности, где нужно добавлять элементы при помощи SelectMany

Действительно, если мы вычтем из каждого `i`-того элемента `mask` **N<sub>0</sub>**i (**N<sub>0</sub>** - последовательность целых неотрицательных чисел), мы получим коллекцию предрассчитанных позиций, на которые необходимо будет вставить пустые строки

Если проще, нам нужно просто из каждого элемента `mask` вычесть его позицию в массиве

Получив коллекцию позиций, куда потребуется вставить пустые строки, мы уже используем все тот же `SelectMany`

---

*Итоговый код:*

```
// Определим данные
IEnumerable<string> collection = new List<string> { "Some", "Strings", "To", "Test", "Method" };
IEnumerable<int> mask = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };

// Просчитаем маску
mask = mask.Select((x, i) => x - i);

// Для каждого элемента выберем коллекцию, которая состоит из такого числа пустых строк, сколько раз индекс объекта 
// встречается в маске, а также из этого самого элемента
IEnumerable<string> result = collection.SelectMany((x, i) => new List<string>(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, mask.Count(index => index == i))) { x });
```

*Результат:*

```
// IEnumerable<string> result:
"Some"
""
""
"Strings"
""
"To"
"Test"
"Method"
```

Собственно, мы получили как раз то, что и ожидали)

Еще раз большое спасибо за хорошую идею!

Comment: Как раз зашёл писать ответ :)